# rails devise authentication with ruby lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, devise

I'm using rails with devise. How can I change this to rather check a given email address?

This is the working original code

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

I tried this but it threw an `undefined method "call" for #<Hash:0x007ffc34e9eca0>` error:

```
authenticate :user, if: lambda { |u| u.email == "xyz@gmail.com" } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
authenticate :user, if: lambda { |u| u.email == "xyz@gmail.com" }
```

That will create a hash that looks like:

```
{ :if => lambda { |u| u.email ... } }
```

You don't need the `if:` there. This should work:

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.email == "xyz@gmail.com" } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

Comment: Your answer was so quick that I had to wait to be able to mark the answer ;)